# Cakephp match against

Tags: sql, cakephp

I'm new to `CakePHP` and I need some help with transforming my `sql` to `CakePHP` syntaxis. I have following code:

```
("SELECT *, MATCH(first_answer) AGAINST('some text') AS score FROM newapplications ORDER BY score DESC")
```

How can I use this code in `CakePHP`?

Comment: You need to be a little more specific as to what exactly the programming related problem is that you are facing, currently this reads like a "_please code that for me_" question, which usually doesn't attract good answers (or any at all). You may want to start with reading how [**the query builder**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html) works if you're not familiar with it, and then check back with a specific problem. Also please always mention your exact CakePHP Version.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what error you are getting.